# Julia Assignment: I don't understand the what the questions asked for

Tags: julia

Just started my lesson of Julia language, but one of the question I quite not understand
(Questions below):
Is it ask me to check the length of name and quantity, if length of quantity is less than name , it mean there are missing quantity in the list, and I should replace the missing[index] with the first order of the quantity list, and price list as well ?

Am I right?

> (Sunny’s Crazy Idea) When Sunny claims reimbursement, sometimes he
> finds there are some missing values on his sheet. 
>   With those
> missing values, he can’t get the total expense he should receive
> easily by doing inner product.  
> To avoid errors, he asks his
> administrative assistant (AA) to create a new function called
> “Account_Manager”, which will automatically fill the missing value by
> replicating the value(s) from the top of the vector. 
> Moreover,
> to be careful, you also need to tell Sunny which value(s) is/are
> missing and what value do you use to substitute the missing value.
>
> The information he has are the names of equipment he bought,
> their quantities and their prices. 
> Example: 
> (1) name =
> [‘Pencil’, ‘Marker’, ‘Glue’], quantity = [3, 4], price = [30, 50, 80].
>
> The total expense will be `3*30 + 4*50 + 3*30 = 530`. 
> Then
> you should print “The total expense is 530. The quantity for Glue is
> missing and filled with 3.” 
> Input: name, quantity, price 
> Output: The total expense is 530. 
> The quantity for Glue is
> missing and filled with 3. 
> (2) name = [‘Pencil’, ‘Marker’,
> ‘Glue’’], quantity = [3, 4, 5], price = [30, 50]. 
> The total
> expense will be `3*30 + 4*50 + 5*30 = 440`. 
> Then you should print
> “The total expense is 440. The price for Glue is missing and filled
> with 30.” 
> Input: name, quantity, price 
> Output: The total
> expense is 440. 
> The price for Glue is missing and filled with
> 30. 
> (3) name = [‘Pencil’, ‘Marker’, ‘Glue’, ‘Scissor’], quantity = [3, 4], price = [30, 50, 80]. `3*30 + 4*50 + 3*80 + 4*30 = 650`. 
> Then you should print “The total expense is 650. The quantity for
> Glue is missing and filled with 3. The quantity for Scissor is missing
> and filled with 4. The price for Scissor is missing and filled with
> 30.” 
> Input: name, quantity, price 
> Output: The total expense is 650. 
> The quantity for Glue is missing and filled with
> 3. 
> The quantity for Scissor is missing and filled with 4. 
> The price for Scissor is missing and filled with 30.
>
> ```
> # Q5 Test 1
> Q5_1_name = ["Sunny", "Hsin", "Eric"]
> Q5_1_quantity = [0, 1, 1]
> Q5_1_price = [1, 10, 100]
> println(Account_Manager(Q5_1_name, Q5_1_quantity, Q5_1_price))
>
> # Q5 Test 2
> Q5_2_name = ["Sunny", "Hsin", "Eric", "Breakfast", "Dinner", "Concert"]
> Q5_2_quantity = [0, 1, 1, 10, 20]
> Q5_2_price = [1, 10, 100, 5, 50, 500]
> println(Account_Manager(Q5_2_name, Q5_2_quantity, Q5_2_price))
>
> # Q5 Test 3
> Q5_3_name = ["Sunny", "Hsin", "Eric", "Breakfast", "Dinner", "Concert"]
> Q5_3_quantity = [0, 1, 1, 10, 20, 50]
> Q5_3_price = [1, 10, 100, 5, 50]
> println(Account_Manager(Q5_3_name, Q5_3_quantity, Q5_3_price))
>
> # Q5 Test 4
> Q5_4_name = ["Sunny", "Hsin", "Eric", "Breakfast", "Dinner", "Concert"]
> Q5_4_quantity = [0, 1, 1, 10, 20]
> Q5_4_price = [1, 10, 100, 5, 50]
> println(Account_Manager(Q5_4_name, Q5_4_quantity, Q5_4_price))
>
> # Q5 Test 5
> Q5_5_name = ["Sunny", "Hsin", "Eric", "Breakfast", "Dinner", "Concert"]
> Q5_5_quantity = [0, 1, 1, 10]
> Q5_5_price = [1, 10, 100, 5]
> println(Account_Manager(Q5_5_name, Q5_5_quantity, Q5_5_price))
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation is pretty much correct. One addition: if there is more than one missing quantity, then the first missing quantity is replaced by the first quantity of the array, the second missing by the second in the array, etc. And similarly for price.

Also, I don't know if it's just a copy-paste issue or if your original question itself has this issue, but the examples are supposed to have `*`s for multiplication, which seem to have been eaten by Markdown. So the calculation in the last example should read `3*30 + 4*50 + 3*80 + 4*30 = 650.`  That makes a lot easier to understand what's being asked.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I already edit my question.